# matplotlib using twinx and twiny together (like twinxy)

Tags: matplotlib

Can I have both twinx and twiny together (i.e. something like twinxy)?
I want to put a CDF on a bar plot where the X axis of the bar plot is in log-scale. I cannot make the Ys together, because the bar plot y range is very large comparing [0,1] for CDF.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to plot two things on the same `axes` with no shared `axis`.  There is probably a better way to do this, but you can stack `twinx` [(doc)](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) and `twiny` [(doc)](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twiny.html) as such

```
ax # your first axes
ax_new = ax.twinx().twiny()
```

Which will give you tick marks on all sides of the plot.  `ax` will plot against the bottom and left, `ax_new` will plot against the top and right.

Comment: Seems to be straightforward... I do not know why I failed to test it... Thanks

Comment: Great solution, thanks! When using this method (`ax2 = ax1.twinx().twiny()`), I was not able to set the y_label for the second axis, though I could set the x_label. By switching to `ax2 = ax1.twiny().twinx()` I was then able to add the y_label. This, however, raises another issue as I'm unable to turn off the x-tick labels (`ax2.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', top='off', bottom='off', labelbottom='off', labeltop='off')`) as I had been able to before. This method seems to break some of the functionality of the axes and may take some time to work around.

Comment: @Jason That is a funny wrinkle in how the x/ylabels on overlapping axes get handled.  You may need to grab the intermediary axes and work on it too.