# Overlaying plots in matplotlib with differing axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am not sure if this is a duplicate, I have searched to find similar questions, but not all are 100% equal.

I wish to plot the throughput of a benchmark experiment in Matplotlib. For my experiment, I have created a dummy experiment which runs multiplication on a GPU and multi-threaded multiplication on a CPU.

I can correctly plot the throughput by converting my axes to log_2, which is produced by:

```
gpu = gpu_datas.iloc[0:11]
cpu = cpu_datas.iloc[0:11]

y_g = (gpu["Size"] / gpu["Time(ms)"])
c_g = (cpu["Size"] / cpu["Time(ms)"])
plt.xscale('log',base=2) 
plt.yscale('log',base=2) 
plt.plot(gpu["Size"], y_g, label=f"GPU", color = "red", linestyle = "dotted")
plt.plot(cpu["Size"], c_g, label=f"CPU", color = "green", linestyle = "dotted")
```

This nicely outputs the following graph:

[image: Throughput of CPU/GPU]

This plots the throughput per second on the y-axis, and the size of work-load on the x-axis.

I now want to overlay an image of the joules consumed by each step, meaning that I have my joule measurement in the same fashion:

```
plt.xscale('log',base=2) 
plt.yscale('log',base=2) 
plt.plot(gpu["Size"], y_g, label=f"GPU", color = "red", linestyle = "dotted")
plt.plot(cpu["Size"], c_g, label=f"CPU", color = "green", linestyle = "dotted")
plt.plot(cpu["Joules (pJ)"], color = "green")
plt.plot(gpu["Joules (pJ)"], color = "red")
```

This correctly produces the wrong graph, as follows:

[image]

But I am in doubt as to how to overlay the second plot so the axes match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the two data pairs are in x as well as in y completely in different value ranges.
To have both ranges, so to say both **'zoomed'** *) to the plot you can use [`axis twins`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html).

*) assuming that's what you meant with 'so the axes match'

---

**1st** some well separated mockup data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_size = np.array([1,200])
y_size_gpu = x_size
y_size_cpu = y_size_gpu + 30

x_joules = np.array([1_000,2_000])
y_joules_gpu = x_joules
y_joules_cpu = y_joules_gpu + 100
```

**2nd** the 'default' plot with the large spread as shown in your question:

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, facecolor=(1, 1, 1))

plt.plot(x_size, y_size_cpu, color = 'g')
plt.plot(x_size, y_size_gpu, color = 'r')

plt.plot(x_joules, y_joules_cpu, color = 'g', linestyle='dashed')
plt.plot(x_joules, y_joules_gpu, color = 'r', linestyle='dashed')

plt.show()
```

**3rd** overlaying ('zooming') the two ranges with twin axis:

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, facecolor=(1, 1, 1))

twin_stacked = ax.twiny().twinx()

p1 = ax.plot(x_size, y_size_cpu, color = 'g')
p2 = ax.plot(x_size, y_size_gpu, color = 'r')
ax.set_ylabel('Size')

twin1 = twin_stacked.plot(x_joules, y_joules_cpu, color = 'g', linestyle='dashed')
twin2 = twin_stacked.plot(x_joules, y_joules_gpu, color = 'r', linestyle='dashed')
twin_stacked.set_ylabel('Joules')

plt.show()
```

**Notes:**

- I may have mixed up your x / y data with the labels, but you can assign it again
- As you see a new 'problem' arises on how to know which line belongs to which axis

  - probably best is to separete them by colors / linestyles ... assignement
- twinx and twiny have to be stacked `ax.twiny().twinx()` to have them related

  - the 'usual' way you'll find docu about them is separate
  - kudos to [this answer from tacaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12359506/11815313) where I got the 'stacking' from
  - the twin y x sequence is important concerning e.g. the labels assignment, see also the next bullet point
- heads-up: twin axis can be a bit confusing (at least for me when I used them the first time) concerning where their respective 'x' and 'y' axis are located - see from e.g. [`Axes.twinx()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html):

  > Create a new Axes with an invisible x-axis and an independent y-axis
  > positioned opposite to the original one (i.e. at right).

  - so for twin**x** the **x**-axis is invisible ... (that confused me at the beginning)

    - the reason is that otherwise there would be two x-axis at the bottom, but there should only be a second (twin) y axis on the right
    - best is to get a basic example (you'll find them online) for just one of them and check it out